# Handle multidimensional JSON with scala Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to send data from the client to the server using a JSON request. The body of the JSON request looks like this:

```
[
 [
  {"x":"0","y":"0","player":0},
  {"x":"0","y":"1","player":0},                      
  {"x":"0","y":"2","player":1}
 ],
 [
  {"x":"1","y":"0","player":0},
  {"x":"1","y":"1","player":2},
  {"x":"1","y":"2","player":0}
 ],
 [
  {"x":"2","y":"0","player":0},
  {"x":"2","y":"1","player":1},
  {"x":"2","y":"2","player":2}
 ]
]
```

On server side I would like to transform data with Play 2 framework to Scala 2D list like this:

```
List(
 List(0,0,1),
 List(0,2,0),
 List(0,1,2)
)
```

this is 3x3 but it can be variable like 50x50 or so.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far and where is the problem?

Comment: well from [play doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonRequests) I can figure out how to handle simple json with known values. But this could be array 50*50 or 3*3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be incomplete (don't know if you want to modelize the square matrix contraint as well) but something like that could be a good start:

First here is what the controller (and model) part can define

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json._

type PlayerT = (String, String, Int)

implicit val playerTripleReads:Reads[PlayerT] = (
  (__ \ "x").read[String] and
  (__ \ "y").read[String] and
  (__ \ "player").read[Int]
  tupled
)

def getJson = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[List[List[PlayerT]]].map{
    case xs => Ok(xs.mkString("\n"))
  }.recoverTotal{
    e => BadRequest("Detected error:"+ JsError.toFlatJson(e))
  }
}
```

In this version, you'll get a list of list holding validated tuples of the form `(String, String, Int)` which has been aliased with the `PlayerT` type to save some typing.

As you may saw, the reader as been created "by-hand" by composing (using the `and` combinator) three basic blocks and the result is flattened using the `tupled` operator.

With this solution you're now on track to play with those tuples, but IMO the code will suffer from bad readability, because of the usage of `_1`, `_2` and `_3` along the way.

So here is a different approach (which is in fact even easier...) that tackles this problem of sane coding, this will simply defined a `case class that models your atomic data

```
case class Player(x:String, y:String, player:Int)

implicit val playerReads = Json.reads[Player]

def getJson = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[List[List[Player]]].map{
    case xs => Ok(xs.mkString("\n"))
  }.recoverTotal{
    e => BadRequest("Detected error:"+ JsError.toFlatJson(e))
  }
}
```

Note that, the reader will always follow further changes in your data representation, that is the `case class`'s fields thanks to the use of the implicit creation of the reader at compile time.

Now, you'll be able to use `x`, `y` and `player` fields rather than `_1`, `_2` and `_3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... second solution is great.