# Serialize Array[Array[Byte]] to Json

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm having an Array[Array[Byte]] and I would like to serialize it to Json in Playframework:

```
implicit val matrixWrites = new Writes[matrix] {
    def writes(c: Matrix): JsValue = {
  Json.obj(
        "id" -> c.id,
        "matr" -> c.matr
      )
    }
  }
```

However I get the error `Type mismatch: found (String, Array[Array[Byte]] required (String, Json.JsValueWrapper)`

What is the correct way to turn a Array[Array[Byte]] into Json?

Comment: What would that even look like as JSON?

Comment: How the JSON should look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle multidimensional JSON with scala Play framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993540/handle-multidimensional-json-with-scala-play-framework)

Comment: The problem seems to be that Play can't serialize Byte Arrays to Json, when I change it to an Int Array it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Writes[Array[Array[Byte]]]` that serializes the array of byte array into some string format ( maybe base64 ).

You may also want to create a `Reads` for the same type to convert back to `Array[Array[Byte]]`.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, I like to wrap my binary data, so the implicit Format has not to be imported explicitly.

```scala
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Reads, Writes}

case class BinaryData(bytes: Array[Byte])

object BinaryData {
    implicit val MessageFormat: Format[BinaryData] = Format(Reads.of[String].map(s => apply(Base64.decodeBase64(s))), Writes(a => Writes.of[String].writes(Base64.encodeBase64String(a.bytes))))
}
```

Comment: This does not seem like an answer.  If you are attempting to comment on a question or answer, please do so as you are able.